# Run NPGSQL VACUUM ANALYZE and don't wait for the response (end the program)

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

How do i fire `VACUUM ANALYZE` for my Postgre database and forget? I need my program to be executed right away after calling the ANALYZE. If i understood right, there is command in `Sqlcommand` class - `BeginExecuteNonQuery`, that do the work, but no similar method for the `NpgsqlCommand`.

Comment: [NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken)](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlCommand_ExecuteNonQueryAsync_CancellationToken_)?

Comment: But you can't end the program - it will terminate the connection and cause all queries to be cancelled. You you need that you might try to start a subprocess `vacuumdb --analyze-only --jobs=8 --host=... --username=... --no-password` from a Windows scheduler.

Comment: It will stop analyzing?

Comment: Yes, it will stop.

Comment: Why there is possibility for Sql, but not for postgresql? :)